# VBA Array multiplication, elementwise without looping

Tags: arrays, vba, element, multiplication

Hi everybody: Following liitle issue:

```
Option Base 1
Sub Test()
Dim aa() As Integer
Dim bb() As Integer
ReDim aa(3)
ReDim bb(3)
For j = 1 To 3
    aa(j) = j * 2
    bb(j) = j * 3
Next j
End Sub
```

Now the only little thing that I want to do is to multiply the two one dimensional arrays elementwise without looping, and then to unload this new array (6,24,54) in a range. I'm sure this must be easily possible. A solution that I would see is to create a diagonal matrix (array) and then to use mmult, but I'm sure this is doable in a very simple manner. Thanks for the help.

Comment: Looping is the only way - mmult will loop its matrices internally -  what's the objection to doing it in your routine?

Comment: Well I have a couple of values in a row in one sheet, a couple of values in a column of another sheet, with vba i want to multiply them elementwise and unload them in a third sheet....I am used to Matlab / R, so I thought the most efficient way to do it is to read the values into arrays and then to perform elementwise multiplication...so I will do looping in this case. But do you know is it faster to apply the multiplications on the class Range or is it advisible to first load the data into arrays, to perform computations and then to push them back to a range?

Answer (score 4, accepted):

There is no way to do multiplication on each element in the array without a loop. Some languages have methods that appear to do just that, but under the hood they are looping.

As you've mentioned in your comments, you have 2 choices:

- Loop through a range and do the multiplication
- Dump the range into an array, do the multiplication, then dump back onto a range

It all depends on your data, but almost always you'll find that dumping a range into a variant array, doing your work, and dumping it back will be much faster than looping through a range of cells. How you dump it back into a range will also affect the speed, mind you.

Comment: So what is the best way to dump it back into a range? ;-) Is as well looping needed?

Comment: You can use the transpose worksheet method on an array to dump it back in one move.

Comment: Application.WorksheetFunction.Transpose()

Answer (score 4):

It is possible to multiply ranges without explicit looping, e.g. try:

```
sub try()
  [c1:c3].value = [a1:a3 * b1:b3]
end sub
```

Same logic as in:
=sumproduct(a1:A3-b1:b3;a1:A3-b1:b3)

Answer (score 0):

I'm not entirely sure that this is possible in any language (with the possible exception of some functional languages). Perhaps if you told us why you wanted to do this we could help you more?